# Cast a mp3_metadata::Genre to String

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to cast mp3_metadata::Genre ( its an enum ) to a String , I tried to do :

```
impl fmt::Display for mp3_metadata::Genre {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{:?}", self)
        // or, alternatively:
        // fmt::Debug::fmt(self, f)
    }
}
```

But it told me

```
Genre` is not defined in the current crate
impl doesn't use only types from inside the current crate
```

I dont know if there is a simple way to cast an enum to String without the impl (I'm a beginner in rust I don't know too much about impl) .

Comment: Either the trait or the type you're implementing the trait on needs to be local to the crate. Since both `Display` and `Genre` are foreign to your crate, you'll have to [implement a new type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/new_types.html) for `Display`. Also check out [the Advanced Trait chapter of the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html).

Comment: You could also just write a function to match on the enum and return a string for each variant if you want quick and dirty without `Display`.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to use `fmt::Debug` anyways, then instead of `x.to_string()`, you could also do `format!("{:?}", x)`

Comment: Thanks for your helping ,my enum contains more than 100 fields its hard to do it in the dirty way Xd

Comment: @vallentin Thanks for your helping , I have never used format! I will try it

Comment: @vallentin has the most succinct suggestion if you're okay with `Debug`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orphan rules forbid you from writing an `impl` where both the trait and the type are defined in a different crate.

So you have two options:

- create your own trait
- create your own type

##### Create your own trait

```rust
use mp3_metadata::Genre

trait ParseEnum {
    fn stringify(&self) -> String;
}

impl ParseEnum for Genre {
    fn stringify(&self) -> String {
        use Genre::{Rock, Pop};
        match self {
            Rock => format!("Rock"),
            Pop => format!("Pop"),
            _ => format!("Other")
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let g = Genre::Rock;
    println!("{}", g.stringify());
}
```

##### Create your own type by using newtype pattern

see lkolbly's answer

Comment: You can certainly also use a macro as a third option

Comment: Thanks for your helping I will try using newtype pattern , if I create my own type trait It will be awful I have more than 100 types in my Enum Genre

Answer (score 2):

If you specifically need the `Display` trait, you'll need to make that change upstream. However, it looks like that type implements `Debug`, which means you can use `{:?}` in `println!` and `format!` and the like (like you do in the example you posted).

You can get around this by making your own type which is a wrapper around `Genre`, and implementing `Display` for that (this is the [new type idiom](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/new_types.html) mentioned in the comments):

```rust
struct MyGenre(mp3_metadata::Genre);

impl fmt::Display for MyGenre {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{:?}", self.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your helping so now I should do                                                                              let mut  genre :String=MyGenre.Unknown.to_string(); to cast my Enum to a String ?

Comment: `let string = format!("{:?}", genre);` if you want the debug format as @lkolbly suggests

Comment: @MeetTitan Sorry but I didn't understand , whats genre in this example ? because I dont know how to use the struct MyGenre

Comment: @SawwAL You can instantiate a MyGenre like `let x = MyGenre(genre)` where genre is your mp3_metadata::Genre, and then do things like `println!("{}", x)` (or, wherever you need the string version of genre, you can instead directly do `format!("{:?}", genre)` like MeetTitan suggests.)